# Javascript: clicking on resized window is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I just started to learn how to use  to show animations in my web pages and I can't figure out what I did wrong in my latest project:
It is supposed to show and move some colored circles around my window and create a new circle every time the user clicks on the window, but I keep getting the mouse X and Y position wrong.
For this reason the circle that spawns when I click on the window never spawns in the correct location but it spawns far from where I clicked.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mitosis Simulation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        h1 {
            border: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        div {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            position: relative;
            width: 70%;
            height: 50%;
            left:15%;
        }
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;           
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mitosis Simulation</h1>
    <div><canvas></canvas></div>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//***************************************************************
//***************************************************************

var N = 2;  //Number of cells on the screen
var cells = [];  //Array that contains all the cells
var cell;  //single cell

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cell = new Cell(Math.random() * window.innerWidth, Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
    cells.push(cell);
}

function randomColor()
{
    var colore = '#';
    var hexa = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var number;
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15.9);
        colore += hexa[number];
    }
    return colore;
}

function ridimensiona()  //ridimensione = resize (italian)
{
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function evento()
{
    console.log(event);
    cell = new Cell(event.x, event.y);
    cells.push(cell);
    N++;
    // mouse.x = event.x;
    // mouse.y = event.y;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', ridimensiona);
canvas.addEventListener('click', evento);

function Vector(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.add = function(v)
    {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
    }
}

function Cell(x, y) {
    this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
    this.vel = new Vector(Math.random() * 20 - 10, Math.random() * 20 - 10);
    this.r = 20;
    this.color = randomColor();

    this.draw = function()
    {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }

    this.update = function() {
        if(this.pos.x + this.r > window.innerWidth || this.pos.x - this.r < 0)
            {this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;}
        if(this.pos.y + this.r > window.innerHeight || this.pos.y - this.r < 0)
            {this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;}
        this.pos.add(this.vel);
    }
}


//***************************************************************
//***************************************************************

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cells[i].draw();
        cells[i].update();

    }

}

animate();
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of your x,y coordinates in `evento`?  Prior to calling the Cell constructor to verify they are correct?  They should be, as they are coming straight from the `click` event.   So, narrow it down from  there to the line that is having them as incorrect values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss argument in resize call ! (See code snippet online example - click run)

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ridimensiona , false );
```

Better use canvas for resize:

```
canvas.addEventListener('resize', ridimensiona , false );
```

Also important to add width and height arg to canvas html tag if you wanna access w/h:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//***************************************************************
//***************************************************************

var N = 2;  //Number of cells on the screen
var cells = [];  //Array that contains all the cells
var cell;  //single cell

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cell = new Cell(Math.random() * window.innerWidth, Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
    cells.push(cell);
}

function randomColor()
{
    var colore = '#';
    var hexa = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var number;
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15.9);
        colore += hexa[number];
    }
    return colore;
}

function ridimensiona()  //ridimensione = resize (italian)
{
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

function evento()
{
    console.log(event);
    cell = new Cell(event.x, event.y);
    cells.push(cell);
    N++;
    // mouse.x = event.x;
    // mouse.y = event.y;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', ridimensiona);
canvas.addEventListener('click', evento);

function Vector(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.add = function(v)
    {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
    }
}

function Cell(x, y) {
    this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
    this.vel = new Vector(Math.random() * 20 - 10, Math.random() * 20 - 10);
    this.r = 20;
    this.color = randomColor();

    this.draw = function()
    {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle = this.color;
        c.fill();
    }

    this.update = function() {
        if(this.pos.x + this.r > window.innerWidth || this.pos.x - this.r < 0)
            {this.vel.x = -this.vel.x;}
        if(this.pos.y + this.r > window.innerHeight || this.pos.y - this.r < 0)
            {this.vel.y = -this.vel.y;}
        this.pos.add(this.vel);
    }
}


//***************************************************************
//***************************************************************

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cells[i].draw();
        cells[i].update();

    }

}

animate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mitosis Simulation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        h1 {
            border: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        div {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            position: relative;
            width: 70%;
            height: 50%;
            left:15%;
        }
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;           
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mitosis Simulation</h1>
    <div><canvas width="1" height="1" ></canvas></div>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```